# Is there a way to get existing window insets after dispatch?

Tags: android

Is there a way to fetch an activity's `WindowInsets` at will, long past the activity's creation, without holding on to it or otherwise caching it?

eg.

```
WindowInsets insets = getWindow().getWindowInsets();
myUseCaseView.setPaddingTop(insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes:    `getWindow().getDecorView().`[`getRootWindowInsets()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getRootWindowInsets())

Comment: Is there a <23 alternative?

Comment: No. I assume no phone before 23 was built with a notch.

Comment: I'm more interested in things like status bars, navigation buttons, etc. for the purposes of drawing behind them whilst simultaneously insetting content so that it's not obscured by the system bars

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it's getting more reasonable to have 23 as a minimum sdk version.

Comment: The support library allows you to do this back to api >= 21 by doing `ViewCompat.getRootWindowInsets(getWindow().getDecorView())`. See [ViewCompat.getRootWindowInsets(View)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/ViewCompat#getRootWindowInsets(android.view.View)) for more detail.